# How to make td link to open in new tab

Tags: javascript, html

I have given link for td element as shown below

```
onclick ="location.href="http://www.example.com"
```

now its opening in the same tab ,but i want it to open in the new tab ,how to do this

Comment: add attribute `target="_blank"`

Comment: [Many similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=open+link+in+new+tab).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `window.open(url, optional_name, optional_argument_string)`. It will be up to the browser if it uses a tab or a window for this.

You would be better off using a real link (`<a href=...`) and styling it to fill the cell. Then users can middle-click (or shift-click or whatever) if they want a new tab. (You could also use `<a href="..." target="_blank">`, which opens in a new tab more often then `window.open`, but foisting new tabs/windows on visitors isn't very nice).